# Webpage to connect to MS Access Database

Tags: javascript, html, database, ms-access-2010

I'd like to connect to a MS Access database from within a webpage. I do not care that much about security because it is only running on internal work servers. I have tried the following code (JavaScript and HTML), and have experienced the issues that are widely documented (doesn't work on Chrome, Firefox etc), I also cannot get it to work for MS Edge.

```
<script>
// Function to Check the login from MS Access database 
function checkLogin()  
{  
    var usname = document.getElementById("tbuname").value; 
    var pwd = document.getElementById("tbpwd").value; 
    // Code to connect the MS Access database using java Script 
    
    var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"); 
    var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = W:/TestDatabase.accdb";  
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 
    // Assume there is a table in MS Access database with the name "tUSERS", below is the query for authentication 
    //var SQL = "select PASSWORD from tUSERS where USERNAME = ‘" + usname + "‘";
    var SQL = "select * from tUSERS" ;      
    cn.Open(strConn);  
    rs.Open(SQL, cn); 
    if(!rs.eof) 
    { 
        if(rs.fields(0).value == pwd){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rs.fields(1).value;         
        location.href="main.htm?uname="+usname; }
    else 
        alert("wrong username or password!"); 
    } 
    else {
    alert("wrong username or password!"); 
    rs.Close();  
    cn.Close(); }
}; 

</script>

<body style="margin:0;"> 
<table width="1000px" cellpadding="0″ cellspacing="0″> 
<tr> 
<td> 
&nbsp; 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td> 
&nbsp; 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td> 
Username : <input type="text" id="tbuname" name="tbuname" /> 
<br /> 
Password : <input type="password" id="tbpwd" name="tbuname" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td> 
<input type="button" id="btnsbt" name="btnsbt" value="Login" onclick="checkLogin()"><br /> 
<br /> 
&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
<p id="demo"></p>
</table> 
</body>
```

Can anyone help me with the contemporary way of doing this? I am of the understanding that `cn =new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")` is now outdated.

NOTE: It is very unlikely that I will be able to convince IT to install any additional libraries etc. The server currently has no PHP capability. I have been looking and cannot find any examples of code outside of what I have tried here.

I am familiar with HTML, VBA, SQL and have only just started to dip my toes into JavaScript, so some handholding would be nice

:)

Thanks

Comment: “*I do not care that much about security because it is only running on internal work servers*” - apologies for the bluntness, but assuming all attacks come from outside a company’s LAN/WAN is a naive and absolutely insane take. Cybersecurity incidents stemming from insider threats have risen “*47% since 2018*” ([source](https://www.observeit.com/cost-of-insider-threats/)). Don’t disregard security. I’d implore you to rethink this design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge does not support ActiveX without a plugin. Try using Internet Explorer or get the plugin. You will also likely need to save your database as old Access 2003 mdb format for the JET driver to work.

You can also use python or node scripts to retrieve records with webserver from MS Access but it's going to take you a lot longer to learn.

Comment: I believe we will not be allowed to install Python, IT policies are quite restrictive. Is there a way to to do this with JavaScript? Or any other method that does not involve installing a library or plug-in? Most users here use either Bing or Chrome. Internet Explorer use has been discouraged.

Comment: No. You have to get an activeX plugin, use Internet Explorer, or use scripts (python, node, php) in between the page and your database. There are no other ways.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will have to admit defeat and give up on this project then seeing as the infrastructure isn't supporting what I need to do.

Comment: Its worth looking to see if IT already has something installed or has an idea. People who work in IT can be pretty accomidating if you know what you want.